# Can't open Ubuntu Software Center except from the terminal

Tags: software-center

I can run the Ubuntu Software Center only with `sudo software-center` in the terminal. When I click on the  desktop icon, Ubuntu Software Center opens, and is frozen and shows a dimmed screen, and I have to kill the task in order to close it.

How I can fix the desktop icon?

Comment: Can you run `software-center` (without `sudo`)?

Comment: probably a permission error, try adding the word "gksudo" before "software-centre" in the desktop shortcut

Comment: Can you run `software-center` from terminal without `sudo`? And if it gives an error when you do that, can you post the error?

Answer (score 0):

The root user has only a few programs under the home folder. Maybe it freezes while loading all of your installed programs. Try waiting a minute or two depending on the speed of your HD. If its your first time successfully running the program under your user name, you may have to wait longer in order for it to sync. Sometimes when I run soft-cen on my netbook it freezes while loading, but then recoveres because I have too many installed programs for such a weak CPU and slow HD.

Comment: `sudo` doesn't change the home directory path though? `gksudo` does but I am pretty sure that `sudo` doesn't.

Comment: @DaboRoss Confirmed; I just ran `sudo sh -c "echo $HOME"` and it gives my home directory, not `/root`

Comment: your right, i wrote that cuz i used to run a program on gksudo and it saved setting under the root directory

Answer (score 0):

It is likely trying to update the cache or you possibly (but not likely) have a corrupt cache.

Two things you can try to do. 1) wait a while to see if it finishes or 2) open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update` to give software-center a head start on updating the cache as it will still need to run a update when opened and it will download icons when opened as well.